# i want to display data on another form by clicking each textbox randomly

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created text boxes dynamically...and now i want to know that how to get id for each text boxes..by their id's i want to fetch data and display it to another form... if it is possible then pls help me..

```java
public class remaind_report extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    LinearLayout l2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remaind_report);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("tracker.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Is Created
                Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                l2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_remind);

        db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("sdcard/tracker.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        try
        {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE remind(renotes VARCHAR(200),date
                    TEXT,time TEXT);");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Created
                    Successfully....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Already
                    Exists.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        try {

            Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from remind ",null);
            int theTotal= c1.getCount();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Total: "+ theTotal, 1).show();
            String[] args= {"renotes","date","time"};
            int notesCol= c1.getColumnIndex("renotes");
            int dateCol= c1.getColumnIndex("date");
            int timeCol = c1.getColumnIndex("time");
            TextView t1=null;

            while(c1.moveToNext()) {


                t1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                t1.setText("textbox");
                t1.setId(notesCol);
                t1.setClickable(true);
                t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff009999"));
                l2.addView(t1);

                args[0] = c1.getString(notesCol);
                args[1] = c1.getString(dateCol);
                args[2] = c1.getString(timeCol);

                t1.append("\nNotes: "+ args[0]+"\nDate: "+args[1]+"\nTime: "+args[2]+"\n");

                t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hiiii...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // do stuf here
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
we can not get position by dynamically generated textview's...so better to use list view instead of textviews to display different records from db...

here is my edited code.

    enter code here

package com.account;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class remaind_report extends ListActivity {

    Button logout;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    LinearLayout l2;
    ListView lv;
    TextView ans;
    String[] name;
    ImageButton home;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remaind_report);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("tracker.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Is Created Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        l2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_remind);
        home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("sdcard/tracker.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        try
        {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE remind(renotes VARCHAR(200),date TEXT,time TEXT);");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Created Successfully....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Already Exists.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("sdcard/tracker.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        try
        {   

            //TextView nTv = new TextView(view.getContext()); 
        lv = getListView();

        //lv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        lv.getBaseline();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        lv.setDividerHeight(2);
        //lv.setMinimumHeight(20);


        String col[] = new String[] {"renotes","date","time"};
        Cursor c = db.query("remind", col, null, null, null, null, null);

        name = new String[c.getCount()];
        c.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
        {
            name[i] = new String (c.getInt(0)+"-"+c.getString(1)+"-"+c.getString(2));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,name));

         ans = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtans);

        }           


    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
    }       

    home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntentAcc_TrackerActivity = new Intent(remaind_report.this,AccountTrackerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntentAcc_TrackerActivity,101);
        }
    });
    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntentlogout = new Intent(remaind_report.this,AccountTrackerActivity.class);
            myIntentlogout.putExtra("FINISH", "ACTION.FINISH.LOGOUT");
            startActivityForResult(myIntentlogout,101);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Have Successfully Logout", 1).show();
        }
    });

 }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        Intent showreport=new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),show_trans_report.class);
        startActivity(showreport);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked", 1).show();



        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any id for dynamically created views.

```
t1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Here using t1 you can fetch data, e.g

```
t1.getText("Some text").toString();
```

Comment: i've already created textviews dynamically...i just want id for generate onclick event on it.

Comment: why you need id for click event? you have already done t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hiiii...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            // do stuf here
                        }

                    }
                });  is it not working ?

Comment: yaa..but that is for only 1 txtbox...i want to do this for each and every txtboxes which is randaomly selected by user...

Comment: is it not working for all textViews?? it should work..or create only one onClickListner outside while loop and set same on all textviews.

Comment: ofcourse it is working but i want different data related to their field by clicking each textbox...through above code it is displaying only one database record by clicking each textbox...